# copying the revisions across repositories without change in the revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository file:///D:/DEV/ADM/LOV/LOV-TYPE.txt which have revisons 1 ,2,3,4,5
and a destination repository file:///D:/TEST/ADM/LOV/LOV-TYPE.txt with revison 1

Since the revision 5 in the source is the stable I need to copy that revision to the destination repository  but after copying the revision should be 5, however the revison of the file copied is 5 but the revison at the destination remains 2 as it is only second commit in destination.

--UPDATE
Thanks alroc for your replies really appreciate. I understand I might be wrong. I am new to the svn or in fact to  any versioning tool. what I am trying to achieve is that I am creating repositories for all the files which will be used as part of the changes ( for the application siebel) and will have  the following structure                                                                        .. DEV/File1/File1_repostory                                                                                  ..DEV/File2/File2_repository                                                                     .. Similarly on other location/server I will have                                           ..TEST/File1/File1_repository                                                                              ..TEST/File2/File2_repository

Whenever I want to move the DEV/File1/File1_repository@rev3 to the destination TEST/File1/File1_repository which is at rev1 needs to show as it have version 1 and 3 only not the rev2 which I have not moved.

This is not the conventional way using of versioning tool but this is what I need to achieve

Please help how to achieve this

Comment: What version control system are you using? You've tagged 4 very different ones, and the answer till be different for each.

Comment: Rely on tags, not version numbers.

Comment: @alroc I am using Tortoise SVN for the same I am just looking for a logic or specific command which can do this for me.

Comment: I have updated the origional question

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this with Subversion is to create 3 "dummy" revisions in the destination so that when you commit your code to it, it becomes revision 5. But what will happen later, when you have to bring revision 1234 over to the second repository and that one's sitting at revision 15? That's a lot of effort for little value.

Subversion revision numbers should not be seen as anything more than a simplified timestamp, marking the point in a repository's history at which a change was made. You're placing too much importance on the revision number here.

I suspect that you're attempting to use your version control system in a way that it's not meant to be used, putting significance on essentially arbitrary data.

Comment: The idea is that I need to track  a particular revision across the repositories... for instance I have three repositories where each one represents different environment so I need to track the particular revision at given time....    DEV has 1,2,3,4,5, revisions and TEST should have for instance 2 and 5 revisions from DEV after the approval from testing team.

Comment: and moreover if i do dummy commit each time I might get to the desired revison in the destination repository though but if i check out the version 3 from source and dummy version 3 from destination will be different.

Comment: You're doing this all wrong. Revision numbers are not portable across repository. Moreover, you should not have multiple repositories for the same items! One repository, and when you need a build for DEV, you create a tag. Then when you need one for TEST, create a tag for that.  What you're doing is counter to the normal practices when using Subversion and you're only making trouble for yourself. Use the conventional processes as outlined in the Subversion manual and countless tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks alroc for your replies really appreciate. I understand I might be wrong. I am new to the svn or in fact to  any versioning tool. what I am trying to achieve is that I am creating repositories for all the files which will be used as part of the changes ( for the application siebel) and will have  the following structure                                                                        .. DEV/File1/File1_repostory

Comment: @SunilPawar again, you should not haver separate repositories for this! You really need to read the Subversion manual, http://svnbook.org/, as it covers the conventional practices for using Subversion *including* [tagging for releases](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.tags.html).